# How to show timer after user logged?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I want to show timer after user login here is code :

Demo : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ne0epvf/)

```
function startTimer_session()
{   
    var today = new Date();            
    var h=today.getHours() - login.getHours();
    var m=today.getMinutes() - login.getMinutes();
    var s=today.getSeconds() - login.getSeconds();
    // add a zero in front of numbers<10
    h=checkTime(h);
    m=checkTime(m);
    s=checkTime(s);
    $('#user-timer').html(h+":"+m+":"+s);
    timer=setTimeout(function(){startTimer_session()},1000);
}
```

but it does not show properly, why?

Comment: Whats the exact problem

Comment: if you see after few seconds it shows 00:00:0-25 etc ...

Comment: may this help you http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/7f5bktcb/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that today.getSeconds is less that login.getSeconds.

You need to do the subtraction on the full date and then take the parts.

The smallest change is:

```
    var today = new Date(); 
    var d = new Date(today - login);
    var h = d.getHours();
    var m = d.getMinutes();
    var s = d.getSeconds();
```

Or use the date formatting that Satpal showed