# How to show Timer according to timezone

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, razor

I want to display Timer on Page layout header.
it should be according to user time zone.
"plz help "
[How to show timer after user logged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25526491/how-to-show-timer-after-user-logged)

Comment: Have you even tried simple google search ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First You have to get TIme ZOne

```
 TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("YourTime ZoneName");


  var d = new Date('@DateTime.UtcNow.ToTimeZoneTime(timeZoneInfo)');

    function ShowCurrentTime() {
        d.setSeconds(d.getSeconds() + 1);
        $("#curTime").html((d.getMonth()+1) + "/"+ d.getDate()+"/"+ d.getFullYear() +" "+ d.toLocaleTimeString());
        setTimeout("ShowCurrentTime()", 1000); // Here 1000(milliseconds) means one 1 Sec
    }
```

Call This Javascript function at body on load

```
<body onload="ShowCurrentTime();"></body>
```

And Extension Method For Date time

```
   public static DateTime ToTimeZoneTime(this DateTime utctime, TimeZoneInfo userTimeZone)
    {

        var timeNow = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utctime, userTimeZone);

        return timeNow;
    }
```